# How to sleep in shell script?

Tags: android, shell

I try to add sleep command in shell script. But it show "syntax error: Invalid parameter '2 when I run sh file. However sleep command can be work fine when I send directly to prompt console. The
.sh file script as below: 

`'#!/bin/sh
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 11
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 325 1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 1343
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 2403
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 48 3
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 1341
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 2401
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 -1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 325 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
sleep 2
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 12
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 325 1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 53 1004
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 54 924
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 3 57 -1
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 330 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 1 325 0
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0`

Can everybody help me to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Update for who wants to know. The answer is so simple, Just add ";" at the end of Sleep command

```
sendevent /dev/input/event2 0 0 0 
Sleep;
```